# Is it okay to switch languages in an email?

Tags: email, language

I am emailing a professor I have not met about a foreign exchange program. They teach Japanese, and I started out by writing my email in Japanese only to get halfway through and realize I would have to look several things up if I intended to continue writing it this way. I regularly email my own Japanese professors in mixed languages and I know a few classmates do as well, but we also personally know our professors due to the small classroom setting of the course.

Would it be bad/particularly unprofessional to switch to English as necessary throughout my email?
If any of you are professors, how would you feel if a student you do not know did this? I wonder if it is annoying to them..

Comment: If you give a short explanation why you switch, _I_ would not have a problem with it, however, I grew up with one language, studied in a second, have coffee-chats in a third and work in a fourth language.

Comment: what is the goal of your email?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be weird to see an email in multiple languages, but it's not completely unusual or unheard of. It would certainly make me wonder what's going on if I received such an email, but it's not a breach of etiquette.

In my own personal experience, I had a lot of communications in German. In some cases, if someone was quoting something, or using terms that are hard to translate, they'd throw in the English and then keep on using German.

Comment: I made similar experiences, however, people - in this case - would often continue in English, until reaching "Mit freundlichen Grussen" (Kind regards)

Comment: I sometimes write mails in multiple languages if the name of the person I'm addressing looks like it could be from my own country. But there is always a chance that they might be children of emigrants who then might not speak the language anymore.